# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, node.js

I had a problem when am inserting data in orders table with mid, cid, ordertotal then it shows an error like this  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`coindb`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MID`) REFERENCES `machine` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)". can anyone please help me to rectify  this issue

```
   here is orders table  
  'use strict';
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   var Model = sequelize.define('orders', {
   id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'id', primaryKey: true}
   mid: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'mid'},
   cid: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'cid'},
   wid: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'wid'},
   oid: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'oid'},
   status: { type: DataTypes.CHAR, field: 'status'},
   options: { type: DataTypes.STRING, field: 'options'},
   starttime: { type: DataTypes.DATE,field: 'starttime'},
   duration: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'duration'},
   ordertotal: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'ordertotal'},
   counter: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'counter'},
   closetime: { type: DataTypes.DATE, field: 'closetime'}
    }, {
   tableName: 'orders',
   timestamps: false,
    });  
    Model.prototype.toWeb = function (pw) {
    let json = this.toJSON();
    return json;
    };
    return Model;
    };

    and machine table 
     'use strict';
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   var Model = sequelize.define('machine', {
   id:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER,field:'id',primaryKey:true,utoIncrement:true}
   type : {type : DataTypes.STRING, field : 'type'},
   bid : {type : DataTypes.INTEGER, field : 'bid'},
   },
   {
   tableName: 'machine',
   timestamps: false
   });
   Model.associate = function(models){     
   this.branches = this.belongsTo(models.branch, {foreignKey: 'bid'});
   };
   Model.prototype.toWeb = function (pw) {
     let json = this.toJSON();
     return json;
    };
    return Model;
     };
```

Comment: This type of error often happens because there exists one or more child rows referring to a parent record/table which does not exist.  So, you should check your data here.

Comment: yes there are 3 more child rows referring to a parent table they are working fine but not working only in orders table where i mentioned in my question